# mass rename zip files to original name but removing part of name

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file

I have directories with a lot of zips in them.

all with different names of software that have been acquired over time.

Ex:

```
Software1_ABCDE-FGHIJ.zip
Software2_256SS-BM42.zip
Software3_aswdfbbgtyyn.zip
```

I want to use batch/powershell or bash to rename them all to

Ex:

```
Software1.zip
Software2.zip
Software3.zip
```

Basically anything after _ and before .zip needs to go, But its all random content... Serial keys basically. The names are to long for my php downloader i made on my server, and limit is needed for other things to function so i need to rename 100s of zips.

I already have a for loop to zip all files/folders in a dir in to own zip in bash.

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

and i already have this bash that takes .exe out of any file name before the .zip

```
rename.ul '.exe' '' *.zip
```

Ex:

```
file1_23434434.exe.zip
```

became

```
file1_23434434.zip
```

How can i mass rename all my zips from
software1_serial-here-1234.zip to software1.zip

keeping original zip name of the software and the .zip extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `powershell` also, this would be the PowerShell way to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "_.*", ".zip" }
```

Short version using batch-like aliases:

```
dir -filter *.zip | ren -new { $_.name -replace "_.*", ".zip" }
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I dont know how it works and dont bother explaining it, I dont get powershell but it did the trick, Thank You

Comment: May I respectfully ask a question?  Instead of using part of original file name when renaming the files - using `powershell` - what would the syntax be if you had several hundred *.jpg file names in a directory, and you want to rename them randomly in order:  1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc.?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sanders Which is it, randomly, or in order? You could do: `$i = 0; dir *.jpg | ren -new { "$(($i++)).jpg" }`

Comment: @marsze Thanks a lot for getting back to me.  Sorry for misunderstanding - what I meant was that the files in question are numbered already, for example:  4038.jpg, 22.jpg, 1.jpg, 333.jpg, etc.  However, there is no 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg (which is what I'm looking for).  Instead it currently goes 1.jpg, 22.jpg, 67.jpg, etc.  So, the syntax can *randomly* rename any of them 1, 2, 3.jpg,etc.  I get an error with what you provided: `ren : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At line:1 char:22`
However, it renames one file to 0.jpg.

Comment: @Sanders You could rename the files with a temporary name first, and then do a 2nd pass. And if you want to start with 1, not 0, then you should initialize the variable with that value.

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows command prompt window run in directory containing the ZIP files:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_ eol=" %I in ('dir *_*.zip /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do ren "%I_%J" "%I.zip"
```

In a batch file stored in directory containing the ZIP files:

```
@for /F "tokens=1* delims=_ eol=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*_*.zip" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do ren "%~dp0%%I_%%J" "%%I.zip"
```

If there are multiple underscores after software name instead of just one `_` or the software name starts with one or more underscores, it is necessary to use two **FOR** loops to rename really all `*_*.zip` files correct:

```
@for /F "delims= eol=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*_*.zip" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do @for /F "delims=_ eol=" %%J in ("%%I") do ren "%~dp0%%I" "%%J.zip"
```

Loop variable `I` of outer **FOR** holds complete file name of ZIP file with file extension, but without file path, and loop variable `J` of inner for loop holds just the file name part before first underscore. `J` has removed also all underscores at beginning of a file name. So `__SoftwareX__Y.zip` is renamed to `SoftwareX.zip`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file path always ending with a backslash.
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`

Comment: Kudos for doing this in batch

Comment: This also works like a champ, thank you, and it worked with even 3 _ in name @marsze :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Filter software* -File | 
   Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -split '_')[0] + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Remove the -whatif to apply the action. -whatif is for a preview.

This assumes that all files you want to rename begin with the word software and there is only one _ in the filename.

Comment: not all names start with software, and some had multiple _'s  but thank you for contributing hopefully it can help someone else. the powershell by [marsze] and the batch by [Mofi] worked for me.